# Wordpress, woocommerce - multiple gettext, ngettext expressions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gettext

I am using the following function to translate a woocommerce labels.

So to translate the "Shipping Address" to "Delivery Address" I'm using the following snippet.

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');
function translate_reply($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Shipping Address', 'Delivery Address', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```

But I can't seem to be able to figure out how to use the same snippet in order to translate multiple labels.

I would like to translate "Billing Address" to "Billing & Delivery", but how can I add this to the same function?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't think I can do this, but apparently I can:

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_reply');
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_reply');
function translate_reply($translated) {
$translated = str_ireplace('Shipping Address', 'Delivery Address', $translated);
$translated = str_ireplace('Billing Address', 'Billing & Delivery', $translated);
return $translated;
}
```